# Why does a screen needs to be re-calibrated every few weeks?

Tags: display, calibration

Reading up on colour calibration of monitors I often saw that it is advised to calibrate the monitor every few weeks/months.

Why is this the case?

Comment: What kind of screen? And what source advised that?

Comment: A general LCD computer monitor, not a specific type or anything. The sources are in Dutch so I'm not sure it's helpful to post them here. It ranges from companies selling/renting calibration equipment to people on forums.

Comment: Ok, but _by kind of screen_, I mean was the advise directed to CRTs, LCDs, or other.

Comment: `It ranges from companies selling/renting calibration equipment` - Of course it does.